# How to get scroll y when much new content in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-easyui

In my project, I use easyui-layout.

Sometimes, I should load other content from other page with ajax. And these new content will be laied in center region of cenDiv.

The ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
        .....
        success:function(data)
        {
            $("#cenDiv").html(data);
            .......
        }
      });
```

Now, I encounter a problem. When  the content is too much which overflow cenDiv, there is no scroll. So only part of content display in cenDiv.

Here is my html code:

```
<body style="height:100%" class="easyui-layout" fit="true">
 <div id="firDiv" class="easyui-layout"  style="width:100%;height:88%;position:absolute;top:95px">
   <div  style="background:lightgrey;width:10%;height:100%;padding:10px" data-options="region:'west',split:true,title='Function'"></div>

   <div id="cenDiv" class="easyui-layout"  style="position:static;height:100%;width:100%" data-options="region:'center',title:''">
    <div class="easyui-layout" style="position:static;height:3000px" data-options="region:'north',title:'',split:true">
       north-John-Stack
    </div>
    <div class="easyui-layout" style="position:static;height:100px" data-options="region:'south',title:''">
       south-Tyrion-Lanniste
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

I have set fit="true" in body, firDiv and cenDiv, but it works fail. Because the height of body, firDiv and cenDiv are changed.

And I tried overflow:auto, but it works fail again.

Just only cenDiv display scroll when content data is too much, while the others div postion is not changed.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both max-height and overflow-y on cenDiv:

```
max-height: 100px;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Without the max-height, the scroll won't appear.

Anyway, you used too much height:100%, both the div inside "firDiv" have it.
You could change them in such way:

```
<body class="easyui-layout" fit="true">
 <div id="firDiv" class="easyui-layout"  style="width:100%;position:absolute;top:95px">
   <div  style="background:lightgrey;width:10%;height:calc(100vh - 293px);padding:10px" data-options="region:'west',split:true,title='Function'"></div>

   <div id="cenDiv" class="easyui-layout"  style="position:static;width:100%;height:150px;max-height:150px;overflow:auto;" data-options="region:'center',title:''">
    <div class="easyui-layout" style="position:static;height:3000px" data-options="region:'north',title:'',split:true">
       north-John-Stack
    </div>
    <div class="easyui-layout" style="position:static;height:100px" data-options="region:'south',title:''">
       south-Tyrion-Lanniste
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Div should adapt different terminators, for example desktop pc, notebook pc. They are different display size. So the height size choose % format, instead of px.

Comment: west div and center div are  parallel, the height of west has nothing to do with height of center. height:100% is ok instead of calc(100vh-293px) is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Delete position:static, and added

```
overflow-y:auto
```

works OK, like:

```
<div id="cenDiv" class="easyui-layout"  style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow-y:auto" data-options="region:'center',title:''">
```